# How to get text size and color from RTF file?

Tags: c#, .net, rtf

I have some text in RTF files. I need to extract the text but color and size must be extracted to my variables as well.

How can it be done with any .NET tools or 3rd party lib's classes?

Answer (score 1):

***NRtfTree** Library (LGPL) is a set of classes written entirely in C# that may be used to manage RTF documents in your own applications. NRtfTree will help you:*

- *Open and parse RTF files.*
- *Analyze the content of RTF files.*
- *Add, modify and remove document elements (i.e. text, control words, control symbols).*
- *Create new RTF documents.*

Check out this article about **NRtfTree**: [NRTFTree - A class library for RTF processing in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/nrtftree.aspx).